# Streamline KDE desktop

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I recently installed KDE on my ubuntu 16.10 laptop and I am really liking the themes and the integration between all the KDE applications. Despite this, my experience had been so laggy that I am thinking about switching back to unity. I have turned off all the desktop animations and removed unity. Despite all this, application load times have remained low and I am still experiencing random lags even when only a couple of applications are open. Is there any way to fix this?

If there isn't, is there another desktop environment that offers the same functionality and integration while being fluid?

Comment: I would recommend a fresh install of Kubuntu if you like the desktop-environment. I am running Kubuntu on an Intel i3 3.6 GHz with 3.3 GB RAM, no GPU, no SSD, just a normal hard-drive. Still using some desktop-effects. It is running nicely.